# Variable value updation gives value change to null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application that is connected to this route. This route is to update the user personal detail, I don't get any errors in the process but for some reason what ever I put the input, the value on the mongodb  is changed to null.

```
app.post('/updateUserDetails', verifyToken, function(req, res){
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'secretkey', (err, authData) => {
        if(err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {
            var userID = authData._id,
                newFirstName = req.firstName;
                // lastName = req.lastName,
                // age = req.age,
                // gender = req.gender,
                // phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
            console.log(err);

            user.update({_id: userID}, {firstName: newFirstName}, function(err, updatedUser){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error updating user firstName");
                    res.json({msg:"error updating user firstName"});
                }else{
                    console.log("user firstName has been updated");
                    res.json({msg:"user firstName has been updated", firstName: newFirstName});
                }
            },function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: If you try changing req.firstName to req.body.firstName, does that fix your issue?

Comment: @Avenar - please post your comment as an answe, so it could be accepted, since it appears to have solved the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log your `req` see exactly what you are sending, you can also use the debugger to understand what is being sent and received at any point.

Answer (score 0):

console req.firstname and check what will print. try req.body.firstName, your route is post call